# How to make an option fade but still be clickable on Android Studio?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-studio, click, fade

I currently have a two checkboxes, where when one is clicked, the other automatically unchecks. I would like to keep that however have the unchecked one become a faded white color, yet still be clickable and readable if the user decides to change his/her mind.

This is the current code I have:

```
 chk1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (CheckBox.isChecked(chk1)) {
            chk2.setChecked(false);
            chk1.setChecked(b);
            chk2.setAlpha(0.5f);
        }
    });

    chk2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            if (CheckBox.isChecked(chk2)) {
            chk1.setChecked(false);
            chk2.setChecked(b);
            chk1.setAlpha(0.5f);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chk2.setAlpha(0.5f)` would make it appear faded.

```
chk1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
            chk2.setChecked(false);
            chk1.setChecked(b);
            chk2.setAlpha(0.5f);
            chk1.setAlpha(1f);
        }
    });

chk2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        chk1.setChecked(false);
        chk2.setChecked(b);
        chk1.setAlpha(0.5f);
        chk2.setAlpha(1f);
    }
});
```

Comment: I've updated my code in the opening post, it works however once faded, it doesn't come back. So, if I check box1, box2 will fade, however if I click box2, box1 does fade, BUT it box2 is still faded although clicked!

Comment: Actually, I also was wondering something else. If chk1 is checked, chk2 will be faded, however if I uncheck chk1, chk2 stays faded, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @ChrisChen this is where `boolean b` comes in handy, you can write an `if` statement inside your `onCheckedChanged` and check if `chk1` is unchecked, if so you can reset the alpha to `1f`.

Comment: I edited the opening post and added if (CheckBox.isChecked(chk1)) {, however, I get a red squigly under isChecked saying that "Non-Static method 'isChecked' cannot be referenced from a static context."

Comment: chk1.isChecked() the method is not static (you should lookup what this means it will help). http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CheckBox.html

Comment: I looked through that, but I'm not sure what I'm looking for. I've tried to do it a different way: if chk1.isChecked(true), however "true" isn;t allowed in boolean

Comment: chk1.isChecked(true) returns a boolean of true or false telling you if the checkbox chk1 is checked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different icons for checkboxes when they are in selected and unselected state. Also change the color of the text to make it look faded.

To help with changing checkbox icons, this is helpful

[Change icons of checked and unchecked for Checkbox for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192173/change-icons-of-checked-and-unchecked-for-checkbox-for-android)

You can use to change the checkbox icon and text color,
chk2.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray));
chk2.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.unchecked);

Comment: How would this work if I only want it to change when the other checkbox is clicked? And for it to change back when it is checked.

Comment: Hi Chris, If I got the problem right, when you click on chkbox 1, you want to fade out and uncheck the chkbox 2 ?   The above lines will help you with same.

Comment: Yes, is there a way to add it the fade, as I already have the uncheck part. I've tried inserting that for b however I come up with an error.